# What is best known space requrement for solving SATISFIABILITY problem in exp time

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, sat, space-complexity

I searched a lot for finding best space requirement algorithm for SATISFIABILITY problem but I didn't find any thing better than brute force that is in DSPACE(n). is there exists better bound? and what is best known bound.

Comment: If it were solvable in space $o(n)$, itwould be solvable in time $2^{o(n)}$, contradicting the exponential-time hypothesis.

Comment: From the opposite direction, any $\omega(\log n)$ lower bound would imply $\bf{L} \neq \bf{NP}$, which is itself an open problem. A $\log n$ lower bound is trivial.

Comment: @MohsenGhorbani,, when you write $n$, do you mean the number of variables or the number of bits of the input? There is perhaps a small difference here.

Comment: @usul n is the length of boolean formula(sat) and not the length of input bits.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I think you can copy your comment to this question's answer. thank you again.

Comment: I have voted to close, as this is not a research-level question. It would not be appropriate for me to post an answer at the same time. I will be happy to answer it if you take the question to https://cs.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, as far as I understand this is computational-model dependent. An excellent lecture on the subject by Prof. Ryan O'Donnell can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_nCBH_lVjGU